# Typescript Function with Generic Return Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type FuncGenericReturn = <T>() => T;
const funcReturnsNumber: FuncGenericReturn = (): number => 1;
```

([Sandbox](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=62#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYHEIIgJwJZIEoTByYJQC8UAPACoB8AFAJTm1TUDcAUEgPYIDOwKADNE+QsQEA5OAFsARlgBcsMWgw5xREuShMVCOYswsoARnZA))

Getting this error:

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>     'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.(2322)
>   input.ts(1, 26): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.

I would expect typescript to automatically infer T as number and just use it. Why is it complaining? What is the proper way to write something like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 41):

It's important to pay attention to where the generic type parameters are declared and what scope they have.  The type

```
type FuncGenericReturn = <T>() => T;
```

is a *concrete type* referring to a *generic function*.  `<T>() => T` means: "a function whose *caller* specifies a type `T` and which returns a value of type `T`."  This is essentially impossible to implement safely.  Imagine if you had such a function:

```
declare const funcGenericReturn: FuncGenericReturn;
```

Then you should be able to call it this way:

```
const someNumber: number = funcGenericReturn<number>(); 
const someString: string = funcGenericReturn<string>();
```

But of course at runtime those will both compile to

```
const someNumber = funcGenericReturn();
const someString = funcGenericReturn();
```

Meaning that `funcGenericReturn()` would just have to "know" at runtime that it should  first return a `number` and then a `string`, based on type information which is [erased](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) before the JavaScript is generated.  So properly implementing a `FuncGenericReturn` would require magical foreknowledge.

To reiterate: when you have a generic function, the generic type parameters are specified *by the caller*, not by the implementer.  It's true that sometimes the compiler will *infer* these type parameters so that the person writing the code doesn't have to spell it out, but again, these inferences are happening *at call time*.  Two different calls to the same generic function could end up having two different choices for the type parameters.

---

Let's compare this to a different but related type definition:

```
type FuncConcreteReturn<T> = () => T;
```

Here, `FuncConcreteReturn` is a *generic type* referring to a *concrete function*.  It would be more accurate to say that `FuncConcreteReturn` is not really a type; it's more like a *type operator* which takes an input type `T` and produces an output type `() => T`.

For any particular type `T`, the type `FuncConcreteReturn<T>` is a *concrete* function type which takes no parameter and returns a value of type `T`.  So a `FuncConcreteReturn<string>` is a function that takes no arguments and returns a `string`, while a `FuncConcreteReturn<number>` is a function that takes no arguments and returns a `number`.  Note that `FuncConcreteReturn<string>` is a different type from `FuncContreteReturn<number>`, and neither of them are a `FuncConcreteReturn` because that's not a valid type.  So the following is valid:

```
const funcReturnsNumber: FuncConcreteReturn<number> = () => 1;
const funcReturnsString: FuncConcreteReturn<string> = () => "";
```

Again, `funcReturnsNumber` is *not* a generic function.  It is a concrete function that always returns a number.  And `FuncConcreteReturn<T>` is a *generic type*, where the value of `T` is chosen when the type is written out.  Since these types are function types, the type `T` is chosen by the *implementer* of these functions, and not by the *caller*.

---

By the way, the relationship between a generic function type like

```
type G = <T, U>(t: T, u: U) => [T, U]
```

and a generic type like

```
type H<T, U> = (t: T, u: U) => [T, U]
```

is that any instance of the former will be an instance of the latter, but not vice versa.  This means that if you *did* have a `FuncGenericReturn`, you could assign it to a value of type `FuncConcreteReturn<string>` or a `FuncConcreteReturn<number>`:

```
const fn: FuncConcreteReturn<number> = funcGenericReturn; // okay
const fs: FuncConcreteReturn<string> = funcGenericReturn; // okay
```

Or, for the `G` and `H` types above, you could do this:

```
const g: G = <T, U>(t: T, u: U) => [t, u];
g("a", 1); // okay
g(1, "a"); // okay

const h1: H<string, number> = g; // okay
h1("a", 1); // okay
h1(1, "a"); // error

const h2: H<number, string> = g; // okay
h2(1, "a"); // okay
h2("a", 1); // error
```

---

Okay, I hope that gives you some understanding on the difference between generic functions and generic types.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYHEIIgJwJZIEoTByYJQC8UAPACoB8AFAJTm1TUDcAUACYRIA2AQ0zQkAewQBnYFABmiVOiy4CREgC5YCtBhz5CxBF07ipMyWIC2EAHJxLAIyyaE9p5nJztSvasOVXRywGRi5TaSgLawBlYBwEAHNNaXiEz3lkHWV9NQRKFOxEkONQSC1kAGEJJBFgCD8SGlYKJhY2MIkIjJzDSTsgzE14Sura+oNGwPdmqFayVgBGDrMvZAapWNShhSrkMfX8uMKEmbnWACJz43CZWQRtkb3CcdyAt2D0710VCaMoAHp-lAxABrQQgEydW6SB5IXY1Z4HApFT6ZHw-XLsAFA0HgzicUrQFCeGgAGigAFUGMBNNRyXBNBTmPMoABtOmUgC6BPA0AAEmTKacaWx6Yzmax2eSKdyblAklBiRRBVT6CKOQzKRK2cB6ZyuAl6OdBOdyQtQtjgWCQFBOIaFuTjecLYCrXi5QALBaaAXIhLkqYfCgJLheo0ms0unHWzhhh1QJ1RqBYTBiTCQlYegBMPreA3JfpmIdjWfo8cTWNduIh2fDpqg5srQJTafxbc4QA)

Comment: **is that any instance of the latter will be an instance of the former, but not vice versa.** should this be other way around?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this syntax working for you?

```
type FuncGenericReturn<T> = () => T;
const funcReturnsNumber: FuncGenericReturn<number> = () => 1;
```

Comment: The question is asking why TS isn't automatically inferring the type. Of course if you explicitly assign the type to the generic it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to make a citation from "Programming TypeScript: Making Your JavaScript Applications Scale" book by Boris Cherny, cause it helped me memorize a *solid-and-simple-to-reason-about* rule:

> Generally, Typescript will bind concrete types to your generic when you use the generic: for functions, it's **when you call them**, for classes, it's **when you instantiate them** [...], and for type aliases and interfaces, it's **when you use or implement them**.

So using a generic to define a function will not infer, but using a generic to call a function will infer.