# Generics with typescript snapshots

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, typescript-generics

I have an entity / interface with both fixed and dynamic keys.

```
type FooType = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  createdAt: Timestamp;
} & {[id: string]: number; }
```

When I pull this data out of Cloud Firestore I want to convert it to an array including the document ids.

```
function snapshotAsArray<T>(snap): T[] {
  return snapshot
    .docs
    .map((doc): T => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
}

function getFoo(): Promise<FooType[]> {
  return admin.firestore()
    .collection('foo')
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => snapshotAsArray<FooType>(snapshot));
}
```

I want to make `snapshotAsArray()` generic/reusable, but I'm getting the following error.

```
Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'{ id: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T',
but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

Can I make it so the generic `T` must always have an `id` property?

Comment: Maybe casting is the wrong way to solve the problem, casting `doc.data()` as T has at least got it error free.

Comment: Also interfaces with composed type data? This should error. A `type` would be better suited for this, not an interface; or a type that is composed of the interface and the object.

Comment: ...fatigue. It should have been type not interface in my example. I've updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The kind of generics you are asking for is [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60179671/795876).
You cannot have a function whose **caller** specifies a type `T` and which returns a value of type `T`, because you don't have the static type information at runtime.

So, you have to provide a specialized `snapshotAsArray` for `FooType` (i.e., not generic) or hint the compiler with an exact type.

- The former is as simple as renaming your `snapshotAsArray` to `fooSnapshotAsArray` and return an explicit `FooType` value in your mapper.
- The latter is a little bit more "generic-ish". You impose a constraint on `snapshotAsArray`'s `T` parameter by requiring it to have a `string` `id`, and then hint the compiler with an explicit return type.

```
import * as fb from "firebase";

type FooType = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;
    createdAt: fb.firestore.Timestamp;
};

function snapshotAsArray<T extends { id: string }>(
    snapshot: fb.firestore.QuerySnapshot
) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => <T>{ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
}

declare const admin: { firestore: () => fb.firestore.Firestore };

function getFoo(): Promise<FooType[]> {
    return admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("foo")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => snapshotAsArray(snapshot));
}
```