# Why is the first value in my Tuple always unknown?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tuples, typescript-generics

My Types:

```js
interface Pair<FirstValue, SecondValue> {
    first: () => FirstValue,
    second: () => SecondValue,
    toString: () => string
}

type StateRunner = <V, S>(state: S) => Pair<V, S>;
```

My Code:

```js
const Pair = <V1, V2>(v1, v2): Pair<V1, V2> => ({
    first: () => v1,
    second: () => v2,
    toString: () => `Pair(${v1}, ${v2})`
});

const myRunner: StateRunner = (state) => Pair("hello", state);

const result = myRunner(someString, someData);
```

In VSCode, I get this:

[image: description]

I'm 100% positive that I'm just not understanding Generics very well (I'm new to TypeScript), but I would think that it would list the result as:

```js
Pair<string, {
    size: string,
    active: boolean
}>
```

What am I missing? Am I expecting too much from TypeScript/VSCode? The main reason I'm confused is that, when I use `Pair` directly, intellisense is totally aware of what the return types of `first` and `second` will be.

Comment: In addition to his answer, here is a thorough explanation of the return type of generic functions In TypeScript https://stackoverflow.com/a/60179671/795876 by @jcalz himself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside: I find myself having to alter your example code just to get to the place where your question exists.  Examples: annotate `v1` and `v2`:

```
const Pair = <V1, V2>(v1: V1, v2: V2): Pair<V1, V2> => ({
  first: () => v1,
  second: () => v2,
  toString: () => `Pair(${v1}, ${v2})`
});
```

and `myRunner` takes just one argument:

```
const result = myRunner({ a: "" });
```

I assume those are what you meant.

---

The problem with your code is that a function of type `StateRunner` claims to be able to take a value of generic type `S` chosen by the caller, and produce a `Pair<V, S>` for a generic type `V` also chosen by the caller.  That's not possible, is it?  Since no value of type `V` is passed in, there's no plausible way by which the output will be a `Pair<V, S>`.  One symptom of this is that when you let the compiler infer the types that the caller would specify, it has absolutely no idea what `V` will be.  So it infers `unknown`.

---

Looking at your implementation, you want `S` to be chosen by the caller and `V` to be chosen by the *implementer*.  That means `V` and `S` should not be generics of the same kind.  I'd expect `StateRunner` to itself be generic, like this:

```
type StateRunner<V> = <S>(state: S) => Pair<V, S>;
```

So `V` is part of the `StateRunner` type, chosen by the implementer, and `S` is part of the generic function type, chosen by the caller.  And you won't have a value of type `StateRunner`; you'll have a value of type `StateRunner<V>` for a particular `V`.  In the case of `myRunner`, it will be a `StateRunner<string>`:

```
const myRunnerAnnotated: StateRunner<string> = state => Pair("hello", state);
```

Now things work:

```
const r = myRunnerAnnotated({ a: "" }); // Pair<string, {a: string}>
```

---

If you don't want to manually annotate something as `StateRunner<string>` you can use a helper function to infer `V` for you:

```
const asStateRunner = <V>(s: StateRunner<V>) => s;
```

And use it like this:

```
const myRunner = asStateRunner((state) => Pair("hello", state));
// const myRunner: StateRunner<string>
```

You can see that `myRunner` is inferred to be a `StateRunner<string>`, and then `result` works the way you want as before:

```
const result = myRunner({ a: "" });  // Pair<string, {a: string}>
```

---

Okay, hope that helps give you some direction.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAp2FAPAMUwZzADU4AbAVwgBpkBlCBAexABMSKIA+ZAbwFgAUMmQwCYAFzIAFAEpkAXm54ohdpSqDh+BsxaTZC7vSas11TcjCNaYKKADm+uYuSE7Ie4IC+yQYJOEaBhQCshYRACMNEQATJxSAG4RkpE0CTEpMTKS6JjhUcix3C5S-EIiYk6GyEka5dometLO3Ol1wlY27o7N1QAGuVBSACQ8SV40o+leMn3eMgDcfgJgAJ4ADig2cJAASuQgINDhxWG08YQ7EJK0LUF5RDTnSwL+zIEAtqv7h9AAgodGGArk1tnsDkdsG4HKdLpBqoMpAAiAAWEFIpEYSJocIgizeIECIXkyC+P0hAJAQJBpWQcEkSKRyBmC2QAHo2fcobYHDQePTXDyPF5OMsCYE4PgwRBydBQicpPgbsDwb9sEROHd8C9lgEwKTvhC5STJdLZUNFSq8Qjgsi0RisTirTJ8QIOcg9QbzcqruasNCPKLXgJPVAIPhyKR9SSyUahjw6QymSzhO7Bv6hfY+QKA-YRUA)

Comment: For those who stumble upon this question in the future, the most valuable lesson I took from it was that generics declared next to the function name (e.g., myFunc<V>) are for the implementor, and generics declared next to the function body are for the caller. That one bit of advice completely changed my understanding of TypeScript. I don't know why I haven't been able to find this information in the TypeScript Handbook.