# Generic type not able to infer

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've been hammering my head on some TS and I can't get my head around it.

I declare some typed generic function:

```
function identity<T>(e: T): T { return e }
```

this `identity` function can be called like this:

```
identity<string>("someText")
```

but I can call `identity` also like this:

```
identity("someText")
```

I believe that worked because TS was able to infer the type by looking at the input type.

Now a different example with some common patterns.
I declare now a type `someType`:

```
type someType<T> = (e: T) => T
```

I can use the type like this:

```
const identity2: someType<number> = e => e
```

But I cannot use it like this, because someType requires 1 typed argument

```
const identity3: someType = (e:number) => e
```

Why identity3 is not working?

Comment: See [Typescript Function with Generic Return Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178347/typescript-function-with-generic-return-type).  You've changed the scope of the generic type parameter, which changes where and how it can be specified.   For generic functions, like `identity<T>()`, the generic type `T` is specified by the caller of the function.  For generic types referring to functions, like `someType<T>`, the generic type `T` is specified by the supplier of the function.