# Typescript, Create string based on type of a templated function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have code similar to below:

```
// this calls a rest api endpoint
function getValue<T>(endPoint: string): T {}
// example of use
const myvalue = getValue<FishToEat>("/fishes");
```

I would like to be able to remove the endPoint argument and get this string from something like:

```
interface TypeToEndpointMap {
  FishToEat: "/fishes"
}
```

The above interface is obviously rubbish but is something like this possible, how can I do this?

Here is a version that will run, but wont work as hoped:

```
interface FishToEat {
    count: number,
    fishType: string,
}

let TypeToEndpointMap: { [key: string]: string } = {};
TypeToEndpointMap.FishToEat = "/fishes";


// this calls a rest api
function getValue<T>(pathName: string): T {
    const endpoint = typeof getValue;
    console.log(endpoint);
    return {} as T;
}

const myvalue = getValue<FishToEat>("/fishes");
```

Tried jcalz version, I am not able to show the final results, for clarification its from Type to End Point mapping I need. The type is in a generic function that we will be needing the strong value in.
edited your version to more what I require, but can't get it to work, [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-22vmuqUyuUK5VqjWFXCEYi3PJ5eNUbNB0PhyNwWuUIA)

Comment: I don't see a `pathName` argument; do you mean `endPoint`?  Which argument do you want to remove? By "templated function" presumably you mean "generic function" (I guess JSdoc might use "template" here, but TypeScript has generics, not template metaprogramming).  Also, for this to be a [mcve] it would be nice if you'd declare types like `FishToEat` and make sure that `"fishes"` and `"/fishes"` are... the same? programmatically related?

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/WolnPw) sort of what you're looking for?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please elaborate in the question

Comment: What's the point of `const endpoint = typeof getValue;`?  That's going to be the string `"function"`, which isn't useful.  I just changed my code example to [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqv2dW) to reflect the new version of your question.  Does it work for you?  Or not?

Comment: Ideally I would want `const endpoint = typeof getValue;` to return either FishToEat or WineToDrink or whatever type I have called the function with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To facilitate the discussion, I will define two different object types and two different query endpoints:

```
interface FishToEat {
    count: number,
    fishType: string,
}
// endpoint is "/fishes"

interface WineToDrink {
    vintner: string;
    vintage: number;
}
// endpoint is "/wines"
```

---

Object types in TypeScript like `FishToEat` only exist in TypeScript code; they are completely [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when your code is compiled to JavaScript. At runtime, no trace of `FishToEat` will exist.  So there's no hope of writing TypeScript code like

```
const fish = getValue<FishToEat>(); 
const wine = getValue<WineToDrink>();
```

and have `fish` and `wine` be usefully different objects with different properties at runtime.  The above will compile to JavaScript code like

```
const fish = getValue();
const wine = getValue();
```

and I think we can agree that no matter how you try to implement `getValue()`, it won't magically know which endpoint to query.

---

Instead of trying to do it that way, it would be better to come up with some idiomatic JavaScript code that behaves how you want, and then give it typings in TypeScript to help you use it.  Since you have to pass *something* into `getValue()` for it to choose an endpoint, we might as well pick the thing which is easiest to use.  Presumably this could just be the endpoint path:

```
// pass in endpoint path
getValue("/fishes");
getValue("/wines");
```

but if those endpoint paths expose implementation details you don't want to expose, you could pass in some other more friendly string which the implementation can map to endpoints:

```
// pass in friendly query name
getValue("FishToEat");
getValue("WineToDrink");
```

It sounds like you'd prefer this approach, so let's work on implementing it and giving it some typings.

---

We need some way to map friendly strings to endpoint paths, so let's make an object that holds this mapping:

```
const typeNameToEndpoint = {
    FishToEat: "/fishes",
    WineToDrink: "/wines"
} as const;
```

By using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), we're asking the compiler to treat `typeNameToEndpoint` as an unchanging map from key names to the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"/fishes"` and `"/wines"`.  If we didn't do that, the compiler would infer `{FishToEat: string, WineToDrink: string}` for its type, which is true, but not useful; we want the compiler to know which endpoint it is querying, so that it can know which type it should expect to come back.

That's another, separate, purely type-level mapping, so we can define it as an `interface`:

```
interface EndpointToTypeMap {
    "/fishes": FishToEat;
    "/wines": WineToDrink;
}
```

Now the implementation of `getValue()` could look like this:

```
function getValue<K extends keyof typeof typeNameToEndpoint>(typeName: K) {
    const endpoint = typeNameToEndpoint[typeName];
    console.log(endpoint);
    // fetch(endpoint) or something
    return {} as Promise<EndpointToTypeMap[typeof endpoint]> // need a real impl here
}
```

It's [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type parameter `K` corresponding to the keys of the `typeNameToEndpoint` object, passed in as `typeName`.  The implementation looks up `typeName` in that object and gets `endpoint`, which the compiler has strongly typed to depend on the generic `K`.  You can run the query, and then return a value of the right type, which is `EndpointToTypeMap[typeof endpoint]`, and also depends on `K`.

Oh, and since you're calling a rest api apparently, we want a `Promise` I guess.  Let's try it:

```
const fish = await getValue("FishToEat") // logs "/fishes"
// const fish: FishToEat
const wine = await getValue("WineToDrink")  // logs "/wines"
// const wine: WineToDrink
```

Great.  The compiler knows that `fish` is a `FishToEat` and that `wine` is a `WineToDrink`.

---

That's the basic approach.  You may be unhappy that there is what looks like a redundancy between the interface names `FishToEat` and `WineToDrink` and the values passed into as the `typeName` parameter `"FishToEat"` and `"WineToDrink"`.  This isn't technically redundant, since TypeScript's type system is completely erased before runtime, and isn't a [nominal type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) anyway, so the fact that you are writing out the characters ⒻⓘⓢⓗⓉⓞⒺⓐⓣ in your TypeScript code as both the name of a type and the value of a string is more of a coincidence than a redundancy.

Still, maybe you want to try to eliminate one of these.  Well, you can't eliminate the runtime string.  The best you could do is eliminate the type names:

```
interface EndpointToTypeMap {
    "/fishes": {
        count: number,
        fishType: string,
    };
    "/wines": {
        vintner: string;
        vintage: number;
    };
}
```

Now there's no types named `FishToEat` or `WineToDrink`, and when you call `getValue()` you'll get back values of the same strong object types, but they will be anonymous:

```
    const fish = await getValue("FishToEat") // logs "/fishes"
    /* const fish: {
         count: number;
         fishType: string;
    } */
    const wine = await getValue("WineToDrink")  // logs "/wines"
    /* const wine: {
        vintner: string;
        vintage: number;
    } */
```

Is that better? I doubt it; It's probably better to be user-friendly than DRY here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5YyDeBYAULpBSAlsAC4QBOAZgsgGJFQAWAKgPYCiIpS2OhApPDYBXMgC4kwEWABGlADT5BBKo1YBPGBElRSFEgHMl-QgF9cygiXLVaSAOokI7ACIHgAa15XBANxt0Cl19IwBuXwEAshBDHSkZeQoI0wILPFShNmA9JFItCAA5cBdOYAATGDYbJABeH0yBBmZ2LlJJACIAejVmaA6TFQIndDcPT06ugHdnKA7fMyQQKCyc0ktMm0oaRCQOCqqbdhYCgFkQGAahpG7epn7JZtZObhTr7pn0OckR0vcSTxvcwbARdABUvi6XSQcCgKxISAgB2qZBh3CYvjipAAaiAADYiCAAClu6n6AEogQQsbiCcSPrMOpTfGCuhtIRDMlC0XDiMAkFQDEjyniNEgAI6Eihi0CQTEQHH4wkkp6tbhMqlIGlK+m-MYAjUstkZARUMTwUhEbJahW0wkAHgA0oiAB7kCorTwQDRsKh5Aq+-3aYqQVrImwAPiJ+WDJUkjvJVyGwjWiPDqPqMaKJTDlRRpAA2lmQxAALqagQpqBsPEQAB0eLYhiJwsOZGZjUI3KoCvgTBb6dIibYFCQ1cgpCYRkihAoCpEFH5GEWyyQAAUKGwwIwIPb9nmjmwTtpzjAiwG-a386WI0huegIOUlkg5-jiGAYHikPc5wsQYRlg0YB4AFc1LWtKg2DYIlEz4a4qx4O46iWKYQCIHhtTpFV1DVUgmTvaFG0MFZST6OYZwIbkEIFdRHhwl51k7AhqM+ZB6hAVD0JtRUsI6PU2H+Lx8IIpA8SIYibmmRkKJEljnB+Zx9S8P9Mkg6DyQ2dJcFlaA4F2FgpjYBpfGo4sczKA8MyTFRVQYyY7n6QYhn4wSJkk1jyMyFcVgQ-9rDIbZ7H3NtSGOM4LmswRSPub5Ivg0QJASORFBk00cIKEIPGMGSzArQgGS+DpJDg65CGiUggky8JUrKmxYniaRkuSHLNS01SwKtflMIdZ0IDdYVPW9QMs2GgoS1zEKozMyB41gmTqKvGpMzG8zgvzc9Y0gct5uyatawbJsB0soc8so6Ee1IPsjpC4dR3HBUp2AQwZLnUgFyXbz103bcoF3NbD2PCBTw2iBA0WsgbxEh8nxAF8IDfIgPy-H8IBU3xAOA0DgPA-k1JguLCGopD2M4jDbR1bCWgY-DuSIkiejJTzrnBVZcjuYqasJhL2iSpJTpUO5Aaqp7+cWVkdtTVjkI4tCyZ45U+MUgTxmE2mm3pjz5iYu8wVZnhWI57WokCShhcMfnjZiOJJEavmcqQcWTWBVSoJg3AzCAA)

Comment: Really detailed, and fills in all of my blank bits tin the original question, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to not be possible, cannot get type of a generic function from within it. re [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178347/typescript-function-with-generic-return-type) so unable to get type string to map to get endpoint.

Comment: If you're trying to get type information at runtime, no it's not possible. If you're trying to strongly type our `getValue()` function so that it knows that `"/fishes"` maps to `FishToEat`, then it definitely *is* possible.  It sounds like you are hoping that you could call `getValue<FishToEat>()`, which won't work because that compiles to `getValue()` at runtime.  But you *can* call `getValue("/fishes")` and the compiler will know that `FishToEat` will come out.  You can even do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2KejN) so you can call `getValue("FishToEat")`. Does that work for you?

Comment: jcalz, looks like I could use it like that. If you can post that I will try and accept it as an answer. BTW big thanks.