# How to write a function that satisfies an inline generic type?

Tags: typescript

How I can write a function that has the type Function3 ?

```
type ParamType<T> = T;
type Function3 = <T, S>(obs: ParamType<T>) => ParamType<S>;
const ofunc3: Function3 = <Number, String>(a: Number) => "string ret"; // error
```

But this example is working:

```
type Function2<T, S> = (obj: ParamType<T>) => ParamType<S>;
const ofunc2: Function2<number, string> = (a: number) => "string ret";
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwCrggHlQPigXilQG4AoUSKAMQFcA7AY2AEsB7OgZgKmwBooAyjgAUrAEYArAFyxEKdJGw4AlATzwkaDJiFlyGavSZs6AJj6C8hUZJkb523Kvzq5WxbtJfSDdgGdgKFYAMyNTGVpGFnZzOhpkMQgEfgCEZjoAcysoYTgZOISk5zwAIlT0jKgECGASvV86AKDQxg4Io2jObkwAOXjE5MFgNMyRPKg+woRiqDLhiqqautIgA)

My question is related only to TS syntax.
In this link I'm try to write TS method decorator in two way: one - working and second using type MethodDecorator.

[LINK to TS playground - method decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=21&pln=19&pc=36#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-IEo6E0hkOl1oJp-QxkhnVplOtkfXSGWh8nlCvcSstWln1tA+n8vmLMcVjWThQQsM5nKAAKrOAV16TwBhfUC4hbSAAC9sYomKrDwDBdaAAklOhIg0OAdxr+Tk3dI6ODupPp-vDwwidqPXwL84r-eu6SFsLyp9WBKmrew6jtAoiwiKgT-AQkDIEIf7dGuG7UNuwhWiIMJAA)

The main problem - MethodDecorator is not generic method and then I'm try to use it:

```
function Method2(): MethodDecorator {
  return <FuncType,>(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, propertyDescriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<FuncType>) => {
    propertyDescriptor.value =func1
  };
}
```

I see error: "Type 'FuncType' is not assignable to type 'FuncType'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated."

Comment: Your `Function3` type doesn't seem very sensible - you are promising the caller that whatever two types they specify, they can call your function, pass in something of the first type, and receive something of the (potentially completely unrelated) second type - without the function even *knowing* what types were specified due to type erasure. Are you sure this is what you actually intended?

Comment: I agree, the example is contrived, I'm just trying to understand TS syntaxis.
For example - standard TS type has MethodDecorator and inside type : "descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>" and I can't understand how to write
descriptor.value = ()=>{}

Comment: Note that in line 3 of your first example, `<Number, String>` are NOT passing generic parameters to `Function3`.  You are just defining type parameters for your anonymous function.  It's the same as if you wrote `<T,U>(a:T)=>"string ret"`.  If you could provide a little more information about what you are trying to do, we might be able to give a little more help.

Comment: If you are just trying to understand Typescript's syntax, then your `ofunc3` is *syntactically* correct; but presumably you also want to fix the type error, and you can't do that in any sensible way because your function doesn't have a sensible type. So for you to get a useful answer, you're going to have to explain what you are trying to achieve with code like this.

Comment: My final goal - to write a method decorator using type MethodDecorator - that is not generic type:
https://tsplay.dev/WK7XGW

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178347/typescript-function-with-generic-return-type or at least it has the same underlying issue (type parameter scope for generic functions vs that for generic *types* which represent functions.)  Please look at the question and answer there and let me know if you have any unanswered questions.  If so, please [edit] the question to distinguish it from the other q/a.

Comment: jcalz, thank you very march for your brilliant post!!! I can't find "generic function" in the documentation and you exactly explain this. Thank you again! But I can't understand how to solve error in  propertyDescriptor.value =func1 in my second [TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJR0VW)
 Can you, please, help me ?

Comment: I think you should make his question about one thing; either the question as asked at the top, or the "main problem" on the bottom.  They are two different questions with two different answers. See [One question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)  The second question seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/62623637/2887218

Answer (score 1):

You can cast return value to make it work, e.g. *as unknown as String*

```
const ofunc3: Function3 = <Number, String>(a: Number) => "string ret" as unknown as String;
```