# Can we define generic types in TypeScript for type predicate functions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, predicate

I was trying to create a generic type predicate function but I am getting an odd error which I cannot find much information on while Google - so I am wondering if it's possible to achieve the following:

```
type Items<T = any> = { [item: string]: T }

type Cart<T = any> = {
  cart: Items<T>
}

type OptionalCart<T = any> = Partial<Cart<T>>

type SessionHasCart = <T extends Items = Items>(session: OptionalCart<T>) => session is Cart<T>

const sessionHasCart: SessionHasCart = (session) => {
  return (session as Cart).cart !== undefined
}
```

[Playground in action here.](https://tsplay.dev/w8LR9w)

I am getting the following error: `Type '(session: Partial<Cart<Items<any>>>) => boolean' is not assignable to type 'SessionHasCart<Items<any>>'. Signature '(session: Partial<Cart<Items<any>>>): boolean' must be a type predicate.ts(2322)`

Comment: I don't quite understand the goal with your generic type arguments, but you would need to annotate the arrow function as being a type guard like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5LR5w); type predicates don't get inferred contextually.  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes sorry I was trying to find a simple example (this is the best I could come up with). My real problem is much more complex (trying to extend Next.js types). But from your example, if I understand correctly, the type's default generic values are ignored and you need to re-specify them?

Comment: The type annotation is not ignored, it is *checked*. The compiler checks whether the function has the type you specified in the annotation. Because it doesn't, you get an error.

Comment: Not really, no.  Or rather, the whole type is "ignored".  There's no contextual inference of a type predicate, as per [ms/TS#5951](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5951).  So you have to write `: session is Cart<Items>` there like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wERJgN).  If you just write `session is Cart`, then that's `Cart<any>` (since your default behaves that way), not `Cart<Items>`.  But I feel like defaults are distractions from your main question, or else you have some preconceptions about defaults that need to be spelled out in the question.  Which is it?

Comment: Yes, I was making more tests... it doesn't seem possible to call `sessionHasCart` with a type like `sessionHasCart<myItems>` - I get another weird error `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.`?

Comment: Reading the link you posted, it looks like it's not possible? I basically have a generic type as an argument which can have very different values. One of these is an object with certain properties which can be specified using a generic. I was basically trying to create a generic type guard to avoid creating multiple ones, but I am starting to think this is just not supported.

Comment: Because `sessionHasCart` is not a generic function and `SessionHasCart<T>` is not the type of a generic function.  You need to move the generic type parameter to the scope of the function call signature and not the type.  Maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7yRGW) is what you want (and note `SessionHasCart` as a type is essentially superfluous, so I removed it... you could write `type SessionHasCart = typeof sessionHasCart` if you want).  Is *this* what you're looking for?  If not, what's missing?

Comment: `type Foo<T> = (x: T) => T` and `type Foo = <T>(x: T) => T` are two different (but related) things.  You want the latter and not the former, I think, but no matter what you should be [aware of the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60179671/2887218)

Comment: Ah wow yeah, definitely a typo there. This is really helpful. I think I'm getting close to something

Comment: Going back to the question, did I understand correctly that it's impossible to apply a type with generics on a type guard, other than adding the generics directly in the type guard function itself?

Comment: Treat a type predicate as a whole 'nother type from `boolean`. You can think of type predicates as being a more specific boolean type. Now it doesn't make sense to assign a boolean return type to a type predicate return type, right?

Comment: I guess not but is there a way to Type this so that it works, or basically type predicates are just different?

Answer (score 1):

##### TL;DR;

Yes, you can defined types for predicates with or without generics.
But you cannot assign any function returning a boolean to it, only those predicates.

##### The long version

A type cannot be narrowed on assignment. A predicate function is "more specific" than a function returning a boolean.

See these two types:

```
type SessionIsCart = (session: Session) => session is Cart;

type SessionTest = (session: Session) => boolean;
```

Every `SessionIsCart` is a `SessionTest`, but not the opposite.

For example:

```
function IsSessionExplicitlyNotACart(session: Session): boolean {
  // Differentiate between {} and {items: undefined}
  return 'items' in session && session.items === undefined;
}
```

That function also returns a boolean, but it is not a predicate that checks if the `session` is a `Cart`.

Your function has no signature, so it is inferred from the `return` that it returns a boolean. It is assignable to the `SessionTest` above, but not `SessionIsCart`. For the function to become a predicate, you must explicitly tell TS that the boolean returned by this function has a special meaning by writing the entire signature:

```
const sessionHasCart: SessionHasCart = (session: Session): session is Cart => {
  return (session as Cart).cart !== undefined
}
```

Or the [generic version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsDOAeAKlAvFAhgOxAD4soBvKAbQEt4EAuKJYAJyrwHMBdBjAXwCh+oSFADCOZsHQl8REqX5QoAYwnAGcRKjSF+AoeGgB5MMCoB7PDgA24ydOyzi2AApqqNlHak7dBkQDKEEhIFngAEjhI3iTSEAAe8HgAJkiwtGnYmsiEABRIwaGWDCZmljbe6IQAlFjEBSFhUFRplTqCypZMjIVhkdFqDEGNlv0x2HGJEClp2ZnpWnkNRXglpmEValXVDMtNLWJbOnVkilDMEMAArsx4UPm9lritatUAdKqSUACEmNhXKQgADM2BBknogA)

As @caTS mentioned in the comments, type predicates are a subset of the `boolean` type, much like symbol constants are a subset of the `symbol` type and string literals are a subset of the `string` type. But they are normal types.

Also, a type guard can be generic and take part in inference without any problems.

[This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUFcAdoewE4BdQDNGgQUwIYBM4A7AGwE9RoE5oBnAKCwA95lQlTotQBBQ0gJSwBjRHlABeUIPxEyAHkEiEeOTSQIAloQDmAGlA4+APiMBuOg2aIU7TqADSWUjQDyqOQBVQTJFkJ4aHj5FUSMJUABRRnUcISRPb2i-ANAtVCwEUABVUAB+UABrJzhUbNAALkLi0o99NU0dMwsmFhsOLkEAR0gNbEdnBJ9kwN4BYVF9e0Tff0D+13cPE3CvADJQAG86UFAAbQAFVMIHAF0AWlzKgDkiK8hiYhwAI2IsTwOTpoBfc0tWtnaoAAYognho8PNBklZkExko8JNpsMHE4Fp5lpI1pttntDlpTpUojE4u99id9JB-FhUFosGIAD6gQj3YjfX4tawAuxdHrYCGo9HhG6EO4PZ6vORbHa7Kb4oqkEqgDwnSoeGUnJEw4Wix4vN5q+yfPIOCpMrAANwydC+u3liuVTT+nNsXBc0CQGiIOGIkK8QxhoxCyjCkm1LPFbyle1lx3mbnRKqV6s1KTDYr170NYXyhAtGVN9mtMtR8aWn3ZVlYqEpcU9xwA7hokAALAAi1NpeH2VE4yA0WBoUJmKUD42UiP9KTdHq9PoFS3CuctCCMAAoAHSbyjUDIegeVey7E4ASkqq-NquPEjC5tSgR5vSwvsmYSjICVzY0gVzdLYcFATxcC0xAaEITYGE8cCQCggFaNoBhclw2iQDgyg4tgSCQAgxznqeoC3l+UhYN0j7Pg4IZhNuvZ7jQ655ggpCrtA174bs0AagAhJIzIPMe5hfM0lYoNWhC1kQoCNi2UFIN2O7IKQABq3qQAOQ7IqO8ITtCU7unW3q+iGZrLmum7rlRu79jQB5Hnh56XixBGBCCCBgvyAy1OR2I7O+Hift+WC-kg-6AYk0AgWBKDPNJAFYHBCEuqAyGoXg6FYJh2GgLhlSOcCoLgmR9gURQPYWQOdHLoxzHiDebEauI3Esnx1oWO+AASWDEL2f6gHgWAALZEPUOC+GwzZcC69AiWJxxCGNQgFOiq4APr2RsAktSA75AlkVw8FcragPs-AuECACSHgbZEFUtnFY3YHeoDUDOhDenQCUgv+khRjglygPUcG6DiTy-f9OigIyPHEIDOxCJUoPwRDLLNXQIiEGoaBwHAAAyX5IJUH1HuER6-Og2O4zim2baAADCrXcFcADiERKq1p3gEqADqLigFjp1XBE4AU5TYC+RkXCETg0FwCIfVhWlXCGGI4E4Kg6RxIELbje0gQq74mSa6As3CAUOLrjSxB66uklth2uZdiVfYDquADkODO-oztPM7x7Hqb5uW9b0mydRinKU7ztCN7vs7GbiARLEzarqTLFRjDc0LfDa6k+uOBNTsafG6o6hwVnmPrk8ef50b81Fw02il3A65CE1XxXqAQA) is one example of using type guards for a functional filtering style. I use these exact functions in many places at work, along with other helpful functions that I made.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Just to make sure I understand, in the generic version you provided, you basically re-copied the entire type info the implementation which in my mind means: you can't use generic types for predicate functions.

Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: You can't assign a function returning boolean to a predicate, regardless of the generic. The function itself must have a predicate signature. Since the generic is part of the predicate you need to declare it again.

Comment: So yes, there is no way to create a function type with a predicate signature. If you don't mind adding this on top of the answer I will accept it

Comment: I don't get what you mean. The problem is not creating the function type, is the assignment. The type you created is perfectly valid and you can use it normally, defining a constant with that type is what requires repeating the signature.

`(predicate: SessionIsCart) => {...}` is perfectly valid, you are receiving a predicate by its type. So is `() => SessionIsCart` to return a predicate.

Comment: So the answer to your title is "Yes, you can define the type, but you cannot assign any boolean function to it, only predicates"