# How to implicitly type a generic that extends string? TS2322

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I would like that typescript dynamically detects the keys of an object so that I could reuse them in other places.

See the following typescript case:

```
type ReturnKeysList = <KeyT extends string>() => KeyT[];
const f: ReturnKeysList = () => (['a', 'b']);
```

Typescript complains about

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'KeyT'.
  'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'KeyT', but 'KeyT' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string'.(2322)
```

Edit: Actually I noticed it is not even possible to implicitly type any function return type:

```
type func = <T>() => T;
const f: func = () => 3;
```

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'.(2322)
```

Probably this is a typescript limitation.

Comment: The problem is that assigning it explicitly string makes it too lax: `type ReturnMapped<KeyT extends string = string> = () => {keys: KeyT[], mappedValues: {[key in KeyT]: number}};
const f: ReturnMapped = () => ({keys: ['a'], mappedValues: {'b': 3}});`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a helper function. In general, in typescript functions you want to use the generic in one of the parameters, otherwise you don't let typescript infer the generic. See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60179671/23204911)

So using a type guard, you can use the generic in the parameter, to allow inferring.

```
interface ReturnMapped<TKey extends string> {
    keys: TKey[],
    mappedValues: Record<TKey, number>
}

function isMappedReturn<TKey extends string>(x: ReturnMapped<TKey>): x is ReturnMapped<TKey> {
    // Your implementation may differ
    if (x.keys && x.mappedValues && x.keys.every(key => key in x.mappedValues)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, just use a helper function to parse the type, this allows you to throw an error if the type doesn't match. And may be closer to what you want.

```
function parseMappedReturn<TKey extends string>(x: ReturnMapped<TKey>): ReturnMapped<TKey> {
    // Your implementation may differ
    if (x.keys && x.mappedValues && x.keys.every(key => key in x.mappedValues)) {
        return x;
    } else {
        throw new Error("Keys don't match");
    }
}

const f = () => parseMappedReturn({ keys: ['a'], mappedValues: { a: 3 }});
```

See [the example in the playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1L0KW)